# Nesting Classes in Numba

Tags: python, python-3.x, jit, numba

I am trying to write nested classes in Numba for computing cubic splines. The 1d case looks like this

```
spec = [
    ('x', float64[:]),               # a simple scalar field
    ('y', float64[:]),
    ('b', nb.types.List(nb.float64) ),
    ('c', float64[:]),
    ('d', nb.types.List(nb.float64)),
    ('w', nb.types.List(nb.float64)),
    ('nx', int32),
    ('a', nb.types.List(nb.float64)),
    
]

@jitclass(spec)
class Spline:
    """
    Cubic Spline class
    """
```

and works fine. I then write the 2d case as

```
spline_1d_type = deferred_type()
spline_1d_type.define(Spline.class_type.instance_type)

spec_2d = [('s0',float64[:]),('sy',spline_1d_type),('sx',spline_1d_type), ("ds",nb.types.List(nb.float64)),('x', float64[:]),               # a simple scalar field
    ('y', float64[:])]


@jitclass(spec_2d)
class Spline2D:
    """
    2D Cubic Spline class
    """
```

But this gives me an error

```
TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
- Resolution failure for literal arguments:
Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython mode backend)
LLVM IR parsing error
<string>:498:278: error: base element of getelementptr must be sized
  %".1077" = getelementptr inbounds {{i8*, i8*, i64, i64, double*, [1 x i64], [1 x i64]}, %"deferred.139921649954192.data", %"deferred.139921649954192.data", {i8*, i8*}, {i8*, i8*, i64, i64, double*, [1 x i64], [1 x i64]}, {i8*, i8*, i64, i64, double*, [1 x i64], [1 x i64]}}, {{i8*, i8*, i64, i64, double*, [1 x i64], [1 x i64]}, %"deferred.139921649954192.data", %"deferred.139921649954192.data", {i8*, i8*}, {i8*, i8*, i64, i64, double*, [1 x i64], [1 x i64]}, {i8*, i8*, i64, i64, double*, [1 x i64], [1 x i64]}}* %".1076", i32 0, i32 3
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     ^

- Resolution failure for non-literal arguments:
None

During: resolving callee type: BoundFunction((<class 'numba.core.types.misc.ClassInstanceType'>, '_Spline2D__calc_s') for instance.jitclass.Spline2D#7f420c3defa0<s0:array(float64, 1d, A),sy:DeferredType#139921649954192,sx:DeferredType#139921649954192,ds:list(float64)<iv=None>,x:array(float64, 1d, A),y:array(float64, 1d, A)>)
During: typing of call at <ipython-input-7-8958d720d848> (161)


File "<ipython-input-7-8958d720d848>", line 161:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.s0 = self.__calc_s(x, y)
        ^

During: resolving callee type: jitclass.Spline2D#7f420c3defa0<s0:array(float64, 1d, A),sy:DeferredType#139921649954192,sx:DeferredType#139921649954192,ds:list(float64)<iv=None>,x:array(float64, 1d, A),y:array(float64, 1d, A)>
During: typing of call at <string> (3)

During: resolving callee type: jitclass.Spline2D#7f420c3defa0<s0:array(float64, 1d, A),sy:DeferredType#139921649954192,sx:DeferredType#139921649954192,ds:list(float64)<iv=None>,x:array(float64, 1d, A),y:array(float64, 1d, A)>
During: typing of call at <string> (3)


File "<string>", line 3:
<source missing, REPL/exec in use?>
```

I think it is because the size of the elements in the Spline1d class is undefined maybe but I am not sure. It would be great if someone could point me in the right direction

Comment: I am facing the same issue @arrhhh. have you found a solution ?